# Combining Columns in a Lotus Notes View

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Is there an equivalent of GROUP BY statement in a Lotus Notes view?

Currently my table is laid out like this:

```
| JOB # | SHIP DATE 1 | MODULE 1 | SHIP DATE 2 | MODULE 2 |
| 111   | APRIL 2013  |  123-XYZ |  APRIL 2013 | 654-ABC  |
```

to this (/ stands for a twistie):

```
\/|SHIP DATES|
    |MODULE 1|
    |MODULE 2|
```

The final output would look something like:

```
\/|April 2013|
    123-XYZ (this record would be from MODULE 1)
    654-ABC (this record would be from MODULE 2)
\/|June 2013|
    876-DEF (this record is from MODULE 1, since there is no ship date for MODULE 2 in this month/year only one job appears)
```

Is there any way I could merge the ship date columns together?

Answer (score 4):

Categorization of views is the closest equivalent to "Group by" in a Notes view.  So you're on the right track using a categorized view (i.e. the categories are the rows at the twistie level)

You should be able to achieve this using the setting "Show multiple values as separate entries" in your view.  Set the Module column's formula to be

```
Module1:Module2
```

That means the value of that column is a multi-value list with two entries, the value of module1 and the value of module2.

For your categorized column formula, you should be able to use

```
@Unique(ShipDate1:ShipDate2);
```

to get the column to show the ship dates.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be prudent for ShipDate1 to pair with Module1 and for ShipDate2 to pair with Module2 in the categorized view. Make the categorization formula (ShipDate1 + "\" + Module1):(ShipDate2 + "\" + Module2) if the dates are not necessarily the same (I would assume that since they are listed separately.) That way, the dates and module numbers would match. Though, then we have to have a second column that has a value of "Open the document" since everything else is categorized.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ship Dates column you can "merge" the two fields by combining them with a colon. So if the two fields are called ShipDate1 and ShipDate2 the column formula is:

```
ShipDate1:ShipDate2
```

You also have to mark this property on the column:

[image]